# Arabic characters license recognition

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, computer-vision, image-segmentation, ocr

I am trying to detect the Arabic characters in a vehicle license plate. I already detect the license plate with good accuracy. However, I tried OCRs on the license plate and the accuracy was horrible. In addition, I need to discard the part that says "Egypt" or "مصر" I need to extract the characters only. I thought of training a multi-label model, but then I faced the issue of knowing[image] the order of characters.